# How to count the numbers of cells in specific range which contain only a number,ignoring the text and empty cells

Tags: excel

What is the Excel VBA code Syntax, which i can use, to count the numbers of cells in specific range (A1:A20) which contain only a number,ignoring the text and empty cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub NumberCounter()
    Dim N As Variant
    N = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("A1:A20"))
    MsgBox N
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Another example:

[image]

Comment: I would make `N` a `Long`... not sure what else `Count` can return.

Comment: @BigBen I did not know if "numbers" might include non-integer values as well as integer values.

Comment: Right but the count (result) is always a long, right? E.g. from your screenshot it could be 12.1 and 1.1 instead of 12 and 1, but the result of count is still 2.

Comment: @BigBen  **you are correct!**  the input may be fractional, but the function always returns `Long`.